# HTML Rendering Engine as a Java Control

Tags: java, html, webkit, rendering

We have a client side application (Java/Swing) that we need an HTML rendering control for.

What I want to find is the most widely adopted, most heavily developed, easiest to deploy solution to get Gecko or WebKit into a Swing app (Needs to run OS X and Windows).

The limited (crappy?) JEditPane type solutions are not robust enough for our needs.  We would really like to use either WebKit or Gecko.

Some libraries seems to exist that would allow this:

(QT WebKit) http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit
(JRex) [can not post URL because I am new]

etc.

Whats the best library to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a quick Google search tells me that there is a `JWebPane` in JavaFX.
Have a look [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ixmal/archive/2008/05/introducing_jwe.html).

Comment: Seems to be vaporware. No release date yet, although it could be one of the big bullet points of Java 7 (if it does get included).

Comment: Agreed -- Vaporware.  Might come out some day but has not had any postings in over a year...

Comment: FYI: It is now part of Java FX 2.0 and has been renamed [`WebView`](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html). [Here's an example](http://a1o1.posterous.com/java-fx20-embedding-webview-in-swing).